# Sending Information from JSONObject to Angular component

Tags: javascript, json, angular, api

I'm reading a JSON Object with the following code lines:

```
  <div *ngFor= "let question of data.data>
      <span >{{question.headline}}</span>
      <span >{{question.question}}</span>
      <span >{{question.label}}</span>
      <span >{{question.question}}</span>
        <div *ngFor="let ans of question.answers">
                 <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio"  [value]="j" >{{ans}}</label>
        </div>
  </div>
```

So far everything is showen allright, to post the answer from to the API I need to send the question.label, is it possbile to send data from the .html  to the .ts file if is it not from an input field? How can I do this?

I tried this:

```
  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" (click) ="setAnswer(question.label)"  >save answer</button>
```

but sadly this doesen't work.

Thank you!

Comment: `if is it not from an input field` what does this mean. how do you get the answer

Comment: I'm reading questions from an API, also I can read I can read a label from the API the label identifys the question, so i have to send the label back when saving the answers of the questions.  I'm able to send the answers from the html file to my compent but not the label. Or is it maybe possible to read the label information directly from the JSON Object in my component? How is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You must put the button inside the first loop for it to pass back the correct label. `question` relates to the item inside the `ngFor` loop. If you only want one button then you'd be best to go down the route of Reactive forms.

```
<div *ngFor= "let question of data.data>
      <span >{{question.headline}}</span>
      <span >{{question.question}}</span>
      <span >{{question.label}}</span>
      <span >{{question.question}}</span>
        <div *ngFor="let ans of question.answers">
                 <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio"  [value]="j" >{{ans}}</label>
        </div>
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" (click) ="setAnswer(question.label)"  >save answer</button>
  </div>
```